# compile 32bit code from cygwin64

Tags: gcc, cygwin, 32bit-64bit, windows-7-x64

I installed Cygwin64 on a win7-64 with gcc dev tools and I just noticed that it produces 64bit binaries. (Well, not that surprising :o) Is there a mean to make it producing some 32bit binaries?

I am compiling the socat tool for windows, compiled in 64bit it is working, but I am trying to make another version suitable for an XP-32.

The `configure` script does not seem to support a `-b 32` switch (that I must have seen for ming64 from [this thread](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/atlas_install/node57.html), and if I try to specify the `-m32` switch in `CFLAGS` for `configure` it fails:

```
$ CFLAGS=-m32 ./configure
checking which defines needed for makedepend...
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/cygdrive/c/dev/tools/nettools/socat/socat-2.0.0-b8':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Would the option be to also install Cygwin32, or can I compile 32bit code with another setting or additional cygwin package?

**Edit:**
I have found that my cygwin64/gcc cannot compile a simple `hello.c` program in 32bits:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

with a `gcc -o hello.exe hello.c` it works flawlessly, but `gcc -o hello.exe hello.c -m32` spits

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -ladvapi32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lshell32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -luser32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lkernel32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You could also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206577/can-you-run-a-32-bit-cygwin-application-in-a-64-bit-installation/54216105#54216105

Answer (score 7):

configure is part of autotools, and not relevant to the original question.  There are two 32 bit runtime environments you can build a C program for.  CYGWIN-32 and MINGW32.  I will not go into details on the differences, but a cygwin32 program is posix/Linux compatible (mostly), so I prefer that environment.  Here are the details on how to make a cygwin32 application on a cygwin64 install:

1)install **cygwin32-gcc** package and the **cygwin32-w32api-runtime** package in cygwin64 setup, if you have not already done this.  this will install a c compiler i686-pc-cygwin-gcc and the runtime cygwin1.dll that you will need to test your program (or you can test it in a cygwin32 install).

2) assuming your hello.c program above is to be compiled, select the C compiler and runtime, from the cygwin64 shell by using export CC, or just execute the C compiler as the default make output shows below "make hello":

```
$ export CC=i686-pc-cygwin-gcc
$ make hello
i686-pc-cygwin-gcc     hello.c   -o hello
$ ./hello
$ *There is no output, program didn't work*
```

3) you will note that nothing really happens because Cygwin runtime for 32 bit is not in the path. So add it to the path, and it will execute correctly

```
$ export PATH=/usr/i686-pc-cygwin/sys-root/usr/bin:$PATH
$ ./hello
Hello, world!

$
```

4) Sit back, have a sip of coffee, and rejoice

Comment: Kurt, is there a way to build 32-bit app using `clang` compiler instead of `gcc`? I don't see `cygwin32-clang` nor `cygwin32-llvm` when I run the Cygwin64 setup.

Comment: looks like you need to use mingw64-686-clang for llvm.  does not look like there is support for llvm in CYGWIN32 right now.

Answer (score 4):

***Update December 2022***

All other solutions in this thread **no** longer work !!!

Apparently, Cygwin **no** longer has packages to install 32-Bit compiler and required libraries!

Legacy "Cygwin32" ([setup-x86.exe](https://www.cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe)) can only be installed by passing the following option to the setup program, otherwise the installer terminates immediately with obscure error message:

```
--allow-unsupported-windows
```

Also, because the 32-Bit installation packages **no** longer are available on the "official" mirrors, we must manually use the Cygwin Time Machine mirror at:

```
http://ctm.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa/2022/11/23/063457
```

This way we get a working 32-Bit *gcc* with all required libraries

Note: Cygwin32 can be installed side-by-side with Cygwin64 (in a separate dir) without problem.

Answer (score 3):

Cygwin provides packages containing cygwin-to-cygwin cross toolchains. There are `cygwin32-*` packages for building 32-bit from 64-bit Cygwin and `cygwin64-*` packages for building 64-bit from 32-bit Cygwin.

I've never used them, but I assume they work pretty much as any cross toolchain, so you should pass correct `--host` and `--build` arguments to your `./configure` step.

Comment: I have the cygwin32-* packages installed and cross-compiling still refuses to work. I suspect there's a bug with the deployment of the toolchain...

Comment: @Powerslave, what's your `./configure` line?

Comment: @Powerslave, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @jacerate You just invoke `i686-w64-mingw32-*.exe` (where `*` would be, e.g. `gcc`) directly, and it will happily compile to Win32 in a Cygwin64 environment. A prerequisite, of course, is having the `cygwin32-*` packages installed.

Comment: i686-pc-cygwin-gcc.exe (Cygwin32), i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe (Mingw32).

Answer (score 3):

Adding -m32 to the compiler does not make it select the correct libraries. You should check you have the i686-pc-cygwin-gcc compiler installed. To use that compiler you have to do something like this:

./configure --target=i686-pc-cygwin

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Where do you run ./configure from? From the shell, I get this: -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Comment: The configure script usually comes with the source you attempt to compile. The question asked specifically address the configure script. How to unpack the source code and locating the configure script is outside the scope of this question, IMHO.

Comment: This is right but you also need to specify `--build=i686-pc-cygwin`, or the `configure` script will guess wrong.