# How to compile 32 bit C++ program using Cygwin on 64 bit Windows

Tags: c++, cygwin

I am running Cygwin on 64bit Windows. I want to compile my program to 32bit so I tried to compile my program with `-m32` flag but it came up with these errors.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0//libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0//libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0//libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0//libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0//libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -ladvapi32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lshell32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -luser32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lkernel32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then I tried to install Cygwin with `setup-x86.exe`, but the output program is still 64bit.

**Edit:**
My source include these directive.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <filesystem> 
#include <future>
#include <wchar.h>
```

Basically I want a program for 32bit Windows but there are some directives that only found in Cygwin so I need to use Cygwin.

Comment: 32bit stand alone or 32 bit cygwin ? `setup-x86.exe` is for installing a cygwin 32 bit distribution in a DIFFERENT directory than the 64bit installation.

Comment: @matzeri I am just reading your answer on the other post. My program depends need Linux compatibility so I believe it should be 32bit Cygwin.

Comment: @matzeri I tried to compile in `Cygwin` which is where Cygwin 32 bit installation 
 locate but the compiled program is still 64bit.

Comment: What do you mean as compatibility ? 32 or 64 bit seems irrelevant

Comment: @matzeri I included some Linux directive it in.

Comment: be specific, put all the the info in your question. People can not guess what you want to do. Some directive are generic and can be updated for a build on Cygwin while others require Linux

Comment: @matzeri See edit. I put some extra info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216084/discussion-between-matzeri-and-jason-lam).

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119573/compile-32bit-code-from-cygwin64 TLDR: you need to install the cygwin 32-bit libraries.

Comment: Do an "ls -l /usr/bin/*gcc.exe" to see which gcc's you have installed. To compile stand-alone win progs use /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe or /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe for 32 or 64 bit. If you don't see them, you need to install the mingw64-i686-gcc-g++ or mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++ packages. Then use the long *-gcc.exe names instead of gcc.exe to cross compile windows stand-alone exes on cygwin. Do not use the -m32 option.

Comment: @DougHenderson I tried to compile with MinGW but need `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll` and `libstdc++-6.dll` when I run it. Is there a true way to compile to a single exe?

Comment: There is an option for a static build in GCC. I have never used it. You can use left file.exe to see what DLLs are needed. You will always need windows DLL like kernel32.dll though.

Comment: @DougHenderson I just added `-static` flag which works fine :)

Comment: That should be ldd file.exe